# How to compare unequal columns and based on that pull data from an adjacent column to populate a third one

Tags: excel, sorting, populate

```
Task1 Price1  Task2 Price2
2               2      50
3               4      60
4               7      89
5
6
7
```

I want Price1 to be populated with the Price2 value if (Task1=Task2) if not then zero.Task1 is longer than Task2.

I want to do this in Excel. I don't have access to anything else. Maybe VB but don't know how to use it. I am but a lowly civil engineer don't know much about excel.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first two columns are A and B and your price 2 is D, enter in E2

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2)
```

And drag that down till the end of column D.

Comment: Thank you so much, belisarius. A thousand blessings upon you!!

Comment: If that fits your question, pls check the 'V' in the right side of his answer.

Comment: @Tiago Just trying to clarify for you the commenting system here. If you don't precede your comment with @username, the only one that gets alerted of your message is ME (as I wrote the answer)